# cannot find symbol class BluetoothPan

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth

I cannot import **BluetoothPan** class (`import android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan;` does not work). What can I do for importing **BluetoothPan**?

Answer (score 0):

I had some research in the Internet and I learn that SDK has some internal APIs and BluetoothPan class is also internal.

You can use internal APIs,you can reach them by importing external jar. After importing it, you should right click jar file and choose "add as library". After that, you can import BluetoothPan and other internal APIs.

You can download external jars:

https://sites.google.com/site/hippunosource/home/android/androidnohide-apiwo-shi-yongsuru-rifurekushonha-wei-shi-yong

I am sure, it helps you!

Comment: Also you should not remember that add that                                   defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
} the gradle file!